# THREE.js - How to view-align slices in volume rendering?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I sucesfully build up a volume stack from planes with THREE.js, but the planes are hiding as soon as they are orthogonal to the viewing plane (logically). How can i avoid that; How can the slices be view-aligned? JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WVTvM/)

```
function init() {
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 1, 1000 );
  camera.position.x = 0;
  camera.position.y = 20;
  camera.position.z = 1000;
  //camera.rotation.x = 45 * (Math.PI / 180);
  scene.add( camera );

  geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(640, 352);

  for ( var i = 34; i <= 511; i ++ ) {
    var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'bodyslice/' + i + '.jpg' );
    console.info(texture);
    texture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
    texture.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;

    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture, opacity: 0.05,             transparent: true, depthTest: false} );
    var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    plane.position.y = 300 - i;
    plane.rotation.x = 90 * Math.PI / 180;
    plane.doubleSided = true;

    scene.add( plane );
  }

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: false });
  renderer.setSize( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );
  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}
```

Comment: change the viewport, perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly, you can't simply realign the slices, as the empty space between the texture slices is... well... empty - so you would need to make up some texture data to fill that gap. Rotating the planes would make a mess of the 3D image represented by the slice textures.

One solution would be to have slices/textures/planes in three dimensions (horizontal slices, vertical and depth slices to really make it work). This way when you view the volume from a direction orthogonal to one set of slices, you will face another set of planes. I don't know if it helps, a bit hard to explain, but if you think about your code in 2D, your planes can be thought as a set of parallel lines. But you would need a grid..

Other option would be to extract the invidual pixels from your texture data, and render them in 3D as cubes, planes facing the camera, or probably most efficiently, as particles. Each particle would represent a pixel, and would have the color read from the texture slice.

Comment: is it only possible with 3d textures (opengl)? your second option could be a bit heavy i guess, however do you have a working example? if i render in cubed, how can i hide the cubes borders between each other? what's actually a particle? thanks.

Comment: Yeah the second option would definitely be heavy, except with particles. Particles are a big concept of their own, I suggest you read up on Google or Wikipedia, but basically an efficient way to render lot's of small moving or static points and point clouds. Sorry I don't have very good examples, but you might get some ideas from these:  http://oos.moxiecode.com/js_webgl/particles_morph/ http://alteredqualia.com/three/examples/webgl_custom_attributes_particles3.html http://mrdoob.com/lab/javascript/webgl/particles/particles_zz85_2m.html (last one shows 2 million particles, it's still fast)

Comment: found one: http://lab.aerotwist.com/webgl/photoparticles/. ideally particles would be create in shader.

Answer (score 2):

Addding `side: THREE.DoubleSide` helps a bit: 
http://jsfiddle.net/WVTvM/1/

Comment: is it possible to do something similar to [this](http://schorsch.efi.fh-nuernberg.de/data/webgl-volren/WebGL-Shader.html?data=data/64_Cross) in THREE? Despite the example only uses only one dimension of slices, the plane doesn't hide if view from angle.

Comment: Yes. http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_particles.html

Comment: But ParticleBasicMaterial doesn't support textures [map](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/docs/54/#Reference/Materials/ParticleBasicMaterial) not yet?! So, how is that similar to the above example from Ohm-Hochschule?

Comment: You just need to set the color of each particle as if they were 3d pixels.

Comment: true. however, would it be possible to do this in frag-shader instead of iterating in javascript through all pixels? thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, in javascript you do it only once. In the shader you have the limitation of number of textures, unless you pack all into a single (or a few) textures(s).

Comment: I tried it with the ParticleSystem and ShaderMaterial:
`uniforms = {
 size:       { type: 'f', value: 500 },
  uTex:    { type: 't', value: texture },
  uTex2:    { type: 't', value: texture2 }
    };`
I have access to 2 textures, but if i try to do the following it fails with a lot of opengl errors, like: texImage2D invalid image; generateMipmap; glActiveTexture: texture was GL_FALSE/GL_LINES etc.

`float l1 = (texture2D( uTex, gl_PointCoord ).r+texture2D( uTex, gl_PointCoord ).g+texture2D( uTex, gl_PointCoord ).b)/3.0;
float l2 = ...;
float l = max(l1,l2);
gl_FragColor = vec4(l,l,l, 0.5);`

Answer (score 1):

By using the `lookAt()` function shared by all object3d instances, you can align the slices as a whole object with the following line of code:

```
volume.lookAt(camera.position);
```

assuming that the names of the slices and camera are volume and camera respectively.

P.S. You would need to keep all the slices in one group for this to work well.